# How to get Immutable ID of active directory user by using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am getting active directory users using Directory Searcher but this is not returning all properties of user eg: Source Anchor value. Please let me know how to get source Anchor value of user.

Comment: I've used the SID (SearchResult.Properties["objectsid"][0]) as a unique identifier for C# AD code, but I'm not sure if it's applicable to Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure AD rest api then by default, only a limited set of properties are returned `**(businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, and userPrincipalName).**`

To return an alternative property set, specify the desired set of user properties using the OData $select query parameter. For example, to return displayName, givenName, and postalCode, add the following to your query $select=displayName,givenName,postalCode.

```
**onPremisesImmutableId** - This property is used to associate an on-premises Active Directory user account to their Azure AD user object. This property must be specified when creating a new user account in the Graph if you are using a federated domain for the user’s userPrincipalName (UPN) property. Important: The $ and _ characters cannot be used when specifying this property. Supports $filter.
```

here is the api which you can use to fetch the immutableId

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode,onPremisesImmutableId
```

Here is the sample response for the same:

```
 "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,givenName,postalCode,onPremisesImmutableId)",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "ABC",
            "givenName": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "onPremisesImmutableId": null
        },
        {
...
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, have to fetch immutable id from local active directory using c#. For that I am using Directory Searcher. But Directory Searcher is not returning all user properties.